# sdf robot model slippery, slides no friction

Tags: gazebo-model, friction, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello
I got an issue with a humanoid robot modeled in sdf format. The model itself is fine. However, my problem is the model slips, slides, and can't stay in place as soon as i move a joint (via plugin of window).

The model plug in is not the problem in this case.

I tried inserting the  tags,    tags but they don'e work.
I suspect I need a separate world plugin but i am not sure about this since the model already has a plugin.

You anyone please advise?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1143/sdf-robot-model-slippery,-slides-no-friction/) by [nordegren](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/185/nordegren/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-30**:
Please post your SDF files, and tell us what version of Gazebo you're using.

**Comment by [nordegren](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/185/nordegren/) on 2013-02-03**:
i am using Gazebo I am not comfortable posting the whole sdf file. Can i post an sdf file that has only the lower body, that is with links (visual + collision) and joints?

**Comment by [nordegren](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/185/nordegren/) on 2013-02-06**:
thank you hsu i will saw the mu values and they are way higher than what i have, in fact these values are crazy high. i will post some of the code for the links and joints once i figure how to properly use this website.

**Comment by [nordegren](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/185/nordegren/) on 2013-02-07**:
here is a sample of a link

**Comment by [nordegren](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/185/nordegren/) on 2013-02-07**:\

.030 -.090 .010 0 0 0
        
          1.5
          
            1.00.00.01.00.01.0
          
        
        
          
            .300 .120 .020
            model:// -->
          
          
            
              0.3**Comment by [nordegren](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/185/nordegren/) on 2013-02-07**:\

        .030 -.090 .010 0 0 0
        
          1.5
          
            1.00.00.01.00.01.0
          
        
        
          
            .300 .120 .020
            model:// -->
          
          
            
              0.3**Comment by [nordegren](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/185/nordegren/) on 2013-02-07**:\

        .030 -.090 .010 0 0 0
        
          1.5
          
            1.00.00.01.00.01.0
          
        
        
          
            .300 .120 .020
            model:// -->
          
          
            
              0.3**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-03-07**:
It will be hard to debug your problem without a complete SDF file. We can take this offline so that you don't have to post a complete SDF. Please contact me using nate@osrfoundation.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ideally, it will be sufficient if you can post a simple (stripped down) version of the model that others can use to reproduces the problem.

Here is [an example of usage of friction](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/6b7eba4a3f28/polaris_ranger_ev/model-1_3.sdf?at=default#cl-130) (not a terribly good one because we are using a very large *mu* as the place holder until we get better contact properties).  But in general, contact friction should have an effect in simulation.

It's possible the problem might be more than just contact; for example you can isolate the issue by turning off controllers/plugins to see if friction behavior changes.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0